# Import multiple sybase .db files into SQL Server

Tags: sql, ssis, sybase, sqlanywhere, sybase-asa

I want to import multiple Sybase .db files into SQL Server 2014 at the same time. I have Sybase Adaptive Server Anywhere (ASA) v9 .db files, and Sybase SQL Anywher v11 .db files.

I cannot use SSMA tool because of lower version of sybase.

What is the shortest way of importing into SQL Server?

Comment: Can you provide more supporting data like what version of sybase you are using and what version of SQL server you are planning on importing those db files?

Comment: I have 9 and 11 version of .db files. Want to import into SQL Server 2014

Comment: Just to be clear, you are talking about Sybase Adaptive Server Anywhere (v9) and SQL Anywhere (v11).  This is important information to disclose in your original question.